# How to link two llvm modules?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have two llvm::Module objects and needs to combine them programmatically(I know we can dump to bitcode files and run llvm-link on it.)

Answer (score 2):

Using [linkInModule()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Linker.html#a5a864cc4d71e0234e9f8d786f8716804) and [linkInModules()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Linker.html#a5a864cc4d71e0234e9f8d786f8716804), I am able to link two modules.